# How to show Lists Fields stacked (not tabular)

Tags: list-view

I was wondering how to show a public view of my list data in a stacked form rather than tabular form.

That is, the fields in the list should be displayed top to bottom and not left to right... kind of the way an index page of a blog is displayed.

When I say 'displayed top to bottom' I mean:

```
Title:
<content of title field>

Technical Info:
<content of Tech Info field>

etc.
```

And not:

```
Title            | Technical Info         | etc.
<title field>    | <tech info field>      | etc.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [define the different XSLT rendering template for the XsltListViewWebpart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604024.aspx) that renders the view: [Overriding the presentation of an XSLT List View Web Part](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/04/overriding-the-presentation-of-an-xslt-list-view-web-part.html). Then you will be able to redesign the table for list items.